# Php - Developing Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am developing my first Wordpress-Plugin and for now, all it should do is:

1. On install: Create table.

My Code:

```
if ( ! class_exists ( 'My_Plugin' ) )
{
class My_Plugin
{
    /**
     * Construct the plugin object
    **/
    public function __construct ()
    {
        // register actions
    }

    /**
     * Activate the plugin
    **/
    public static function activate ()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $tableName = tableName ( $wpdb );

        if ( ! tableExists ( $wpdb , $tableName ) ) 
        {
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $tableName . " (
                id INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                any_column VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            );";

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
            dbDelta($sql);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deactivate the plugin
    **/     
    public static function deactivate ()
    {
        // Nothing
    }


    // Return table name
    public function tableName ( $wpdb , $tableName = 'new_table' )
    {
        $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . $tableName;
        return $tableName;
    }


    // Check if table already exists
    public function tableExists ( $wpdb , $tableName )
    {
        try
        {
            $result = $wpdb->query("SELECT 1 FROM $tableName LIMIT 1");
        } 
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return $result !== FALSE;
    }
}
}

if ( class_exists ( 'My_Plugin' ) )
{
    // Activation and Deactivation hooks
    register_activation_hook ( __FILE__ , array ( 'My_Plugin' , 'activate' ) );
    register_deactivation_hook ( __FILE__ , array ( 'My_Plugin' , 'deactivate' ) );

    // Instantiate the plugin class
    $plugin_template = new My_Plugin ();
}
```

But this error is returned:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function tableName() in /www/htdocs/path/to/file.php on line
```

But i cant see my mistake, i am really not sure why this function is undefined...anybody could help me with this?

Greetings!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableName()` isn't a global function, it's a method of `My_Plugin`. The easy way would be convert `activate()` and `deactivate()` to non-static functions, and use `$this->tableName()`.

```
// Instantiate the plugin class
$plugin_template = new My_Plugin ();

register_activation_hook ( __FILE__ , array ( $plugin_template , 'activate' ) );
register_deactivation_hook ( __FILE__ , array ( $plugin_template , 'deactivate' ) );
```

and

```
public function activate ()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $tableName = $this->tableName ( $wpdb );

    if ( ! $this->tableExists ( $wpdb , $tableName ) ) 
    {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $tableName . " (
            id INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            any_column VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        );";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to construct a new instance of `My_Plugin` in your `activate()` and then access it through that - `$class->tableName()`.

You can take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here Function for Create Table in plugin activation
register_activation_hook( **__FILE__**, 'create_table' );
`function create_tabletag()
    { 
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        $query="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab_list(
                tab_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                name VARCHAR(40),
                isvisible VARCHAR(20)
             )ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";
         dbDelta($query);   //This function use to create table
    }`